# How would you interpret the following statement involving "a.e."?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, fake-proofs, almost-everywhere

Here is an edited fragment from an exercise:

> Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space, $(f_n)$ be a sequence of such and such functions. If $f(x)= \lim f_n(x)$ exists for almost every $x\in X$ then $f$ has such and such properties (in particular $f$ is measurable).

I'm confused about the role of $f$. Is it already given in the statement? E.g. if in the proof, one would set $f$ to zero on some convenient set of measure zero, it wouldn't be OK? (A proof which I encountered does exactly that.)

The question probably has little to do with measure theory but that a general "if something shows up in the assumption, must it be fixed from there on?" but I've added the context just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the measure space is not complete, then following statement is, in general, **not** correct.

> Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions. If $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists for almost every $x \in X$, then $f$ is measurable.

Just pick a non-measurable set $N$ such that there exists $M \supseteq N$ measurable with $\mu(M)=0$ (such a set $N$ exists if the measure space is not complete). Then $f_n(x) := 0$ converges for almost every $x \in X$ to $f(x) := 1_N(x)$, but $f$ is not measurable.

However, the following statement holds true:

> Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions. If $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists for almost every $x \in X$, then $f$ has a measurable modification, i.e. there exists a measurable function $\tilde{f}$ such that the set $\{x; \tilde{f}(x) \neq f(x)\}$ is contained in a $\mu$-null set.

Note that the function $\tilde{f}$ satisfies in particular $$\tilde{f}(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$$ for $\mu$-almost all $x \in X$.

Comment: How do you formulate "almost every" when you are playing with non-measurable functions? Do you mean an outer measure of the complement is 0?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Which "almost every" do you mean? The existence of the limit?

Comment: Well If I were trying to prove $f_n → 1_N$ a.e., I would write down the set
$$ \{ x : f_n(x) → 1_N(x) \} $$
and try to show its complement has measure 0. Is this how you'd do it, and if yes, why is this set measurable?

Comment: @CalvinKhor The complement of the set is contained in a (measurable) null set ($M$, in my notation) and that's what I mean by "almost every".

Comment: I see. Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Changing $f$ on a set of measure zero does not affect almost convergence to it. The converging sequence $f_n$ may or may not converge for those newly assigned values but it does not really care, as long as it maintains convergence on the complement of a measure-zero set.

Comment: My worry was rather about measurability, i.e. if $f$ is given, then we can have $f = \lim f_n$ almost everywhere yet $f$ won't be measurable (our measure is not necessarily complete). But the statements claims $f$ will be measurable.

Comment: If $f$ is a limit almost everywhere of a sequence of measurable functions, then it is measurable, so you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @uniquesolution This statement is only correct if $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a complete measure space.